# Symfony login without email verification

Tags: authentication, symfony, security

I install the security on my symfony web_app.

I add the email verification during the installation.

But, I can login without the email verification. Did I forget something ?
I receive the email, I don't click on the link, but I can login to the member area.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like classic Double-Opt-In, and it should only work if User clicked to a confirmation link, since it **completes** the whole registration process.

Consider following steps:

1. Flag for your user entity
2. Authenticators

- `GuardAuthenticator` approach
- `AbstractAuthenticator` approach (symfony 5.1+)

3. Enabling/activating user after click on activation link

##### 1) Flag for your user entity

So successful registration creates a User but **dot not** activates/enables him/her. So you'll need to somehow mark your user entities as enabled/activated.

Something like

```php
/**
 *
 * @var bool
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", name="is_enabled", options={"default": false})
 */
protected $isEnabled = false;
```

Since default is FALSE, you do not need to adjust your registration logic. (Except auto-login after registration happens, then you'll need to remove that part)

Now you have to change login-logic and check if User, who tries to log in, is enabled/activated.

##### 2.1) `GuardAuthenticator` approach

If your login based on `AbstractGuardAuthenticator` (probably `AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator`) you'll need to adjust your `getUser()` (or `getCredentials()`) methods. It all depends on how you'd like to communicate with the user.

Example with `getUser()`

```
public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider): ?UserInterface
{
    $username = $credentials['_username'];
    $foundUser = $this->usersRepo->findOneByUsername($username);

    if (!$foundUser->isEnabled()) {
        throw new CustomUserMessageAccountStatusException('Your account was not enabled/activated yet.');
    }

    if ($foundUser instanceof UserInterface) {
        return $foundUser;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Special `CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException` (or `CustomUserMessageAccountStatusException`)  from `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception` do the magic. [Here's similar example](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony4-security/api-token-authenticator2#codeblock-1431938b6f)

##### 2.2) `AbstractAuthenticator` approach (symfony 5 and symfonyn 6)

Works for:

- symfony 5.1+ with `enable_authenticator_manager: true` in `security.yaml`
- symfony 5.3 to symfony 6+

If you use newer symfony auth system, then you have to do similar things in your `authenticate` method.

```
public function authenticate(){
    return new Passport(
        new UserBadge($email, function($userIdentifier) {
            // optionally pass a callback to load the User manually
            $foundUser = $this->usersRepo->findOneBy(['email' => $userIdentifier]);
            if (!$foundUser) {
                throw new UserNotFoundException();
            }
            if (!$foundUser->isEnabled()) {
                throw new CustomUserMessageAccountStatusException('Your account was not enabled/activated yet.');
            }

            return $foundUser;
        }),
    );
}
```

And again, `CustomUserMessageAccountStatusException`/`CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException` do the magic.

##### 3) Enabling/activating user

Now you need to activate/enable the user after he/she has clicked on the link in the email. It should be pretty straightforward, so nothing exceptional here. Just add

```php
$user->setIsEnabled(true);
$entityManager->flush();
```

in your confirmation action and it should be enough.